# Sprockets cache not invalidated by file change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I'm running a test Ruby-on-Rails app using Webrick in a test environment.  The automated end-to-end test accesses an admin page which causes a JavaScript file to be updated which is used by another admin page.  The problem is that the second admin page does not see the update, but instead gets the old copy of the JavaScript file.  I can see the changed file on the file system, but even if use curl from the command line, I still get the old version of the file.  The test used to work (at least with Rails 4.0, if not 4.1).  It is just now that I am trying to update to Rails 4.2 that this problem has arisen.

Is there something I can do to to tell Rails/Sprockets to forget its old cached copy of the JavaScript that was updated?  I know when I am updating it, and wouldn't mind even resetting Sprocket's entire cache if I couldn't do it selectively.   What I can't do is restart the server each time a JavaScript file gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many approaches to making Sprockets "forget" its cached copy, but it seemed very determined to remember, and I began to have the sense that I was fighting against a firmly entrenched design decision.  In the end I decided that, just for my generated-on-the-fly JavaScript files, I would avoid sprockets altogether, which meant handling the compiling and fingerprinting of the files myself, and writing my own version of javascript_include_tag just for those generated files.

For reference, the compiling and fingerprinting is actually fairly easy:

```
require "uglifier"
require "digest"

minified_content = Uglifier.compile(File.read(my_generated_js_file))
fingerprint = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(minified_content)
fingerprinted_file = File.basename(basename, '.js') + '-' + fingerprint + '.js'
```

(and then just write out the fingerprinted file to public/assets).